# ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android

*everything is ok uri is taking image and path also but when return in second acitivty then image is not showing in imageView and showing this in logcat please help*

**E/ashish: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/FotoAula/IMG_20180329_183302.jpg
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/FotoAula/IMG_20180329_183302.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)**

## Menifest

**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />**
```

## this is first activity

```
camera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.takePic);
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

            startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

          //  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

           // startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });

 private static File getOutputMediaFile()
{
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FotoAula");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
}

private String getPath(Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    final boolean needToCheckUri = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
    // deal with different Uris.
    if (needToCheckUri && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };
        }
    }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}



/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {



            File file = getOutputMediaFile();
            String path = null;
            try {
                path = getPath(Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile()));

            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PictureActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imgUrl", path.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

## this is second activity

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        Log.e("ashish", bundle.getString("imgUrl") + "");

         path = Uri.parse(bundle.getString("imgUrl"));
        ImageView selfiiii = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mySelfie);
        selfiiii.setImageURI(path);
    }
```

Comment: Have you given the required read and write storage permissions?

Comment: yes i  update my question and see i given all permissions

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 ...

Comment: OK. Which Android version is your device running on? And also please tell what is your target version. And which part of the code is giving you this error?

Comment: in every version given this error

Comment: and target sdk version is 26

Comment: and i think in second activity code giving this errror @Rahulrr2602

Comment: If you target version is 26 then you have to give runtime permissions. Temporary you can go to the settings--> Apps--> Your App--> Permission give the permission. Then check if this works or not.

Comment: i already given runtime permission ..when first time app run on mobile then come popup to allow permissions

Comment: Then can you please use a File browser and check if the file actually exists or not in that directory.

Comment: i already use file browser and then show in imageView but most phones have not sd card so not working thats why i use this mathod for internal storage

Comment: @Rahulrr2602    ...

Comment: As correctly pointed out by @greenapps call `getOutputMediaFile()` only once while calling the Camera intent. And then save that value in a global variable. And then simply use that value instead of calling  `getOutputMediaFile()` everytime.

Answer (score 2):

```
  path = getPath(Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile()));
```

You are calling `getOutputMediaFile()` again. And you do it later. So you get a different filename. With a different date-time in it.

That file does not exist.

You should remember and use the path you got the first time you called `getOutputMediaFile()`.

The one used with the camera intent.

Comment: Call what? And what is 'onActivity?

Comment: i called  that mathod in onActivityResult again so i m asking i shhuld call again or not ..what should i do thats write for me

Comment: `i m asking i shhuld call again or not ..` ??? Strange question! Didn't i say you should not?